# Kotlin SweetAlert in Fragment error required Context

Tags: android, kotlin

> Error in my fragment : `SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE)`
>   : `this` Error :Type mismatch , Required:Context

```
root.btn_submit.setOnClickListener {
    context?.let {
        val dialog SweetAlertDialog(this,SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE)
                       .setTitleText("entering..")
        }
    }
```

I've found a solution :  `context?.let {}`

But,still the same error : `required:Context`

Want to use SweetAlert in my fragment.

Comment: if you use let you have to pass "it". and for run "this" works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like below:

```
root.btn_submit.setOnClickListener {
    context?.let {
        val dialog SweetAlertDialog(it,SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE)
                    .setTitleText("entering..")
      }
}
```